# Identify this battery-charging connector

Tags: connector, charging

Can anyone identify the connector in the middle/right-hand side of the image below, which is used to charge a battery cell from USB?

I'm trying to find a replacement charging cable.

[image]

Comment: That cable doesn't charge that battery, surely?

Comment: Apparently it does!

Comment: A 6V NiCd would need getting on for 7.5V to charge fully. Is there a switch mode charger in that slightly larger than average USB plug?

Comment: Could be.  I only have the picture, not the battery or cable at the moment.

Comment: https://www.allelectronics.com/item/con-240/2-conductor-locking-connectors-w/leads/1.html

Answer (score 0):

I have the orginal item - the USB end is not just a connector - it says Input 5V 2A, Output 6V 250mA.  There is a circuit board inside.